A better way SQL 'LIKE' statement with large number of clauses
I need to extract information from a text field which can contain one of many values. The SQL looks like:
SELECT fieldname 
FROM table 
WHERE textfield LIKE '%val1%' 
  OR  textfield LIKE '%val2%' 
  OR  textfield LIKE '%val3%' 
  .
  .
  OR  textfield LIKE '%valn%'

My question is: how efficient is this when the number of clauses LIKE approaches the hundred, Is there a better way to do this?
Using ORACLE 11g
I tried to combine '%val1%' .. '%valn%' into a regexp pattern, but it only become more complex and unreadable.

regular expression can be more efficient than multiple LIKE. Do you have a full-text index on the textfield column?

This looks like a classic example of why regexp_like is so useful. Fewer pixels, fewer bugs.

When you say "how efficient", do you mean how will execution speed be affected? It's going to be slow no matter what you do because doing that LIKE %foo% is going to require a full table scan because you can't use indexes on it. Doesn't matter if there are 1 or 100.

You should reconsider your data model / design. It's never a good position to be in when you have to parse large text fields looking for specific information. Break it out into discrete child rows in a child table, which you can then easily index.

If you are looking for words within some text then you can use Oracle Text to index the text and CONTAINS to filter it.
Given the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name ( fieldname, textfield ) AS
SELECT 1, 'This is some text that does not contain your values.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'This is some text where val1 is contained.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'This has val2 and val3.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'This is some text that does not contain your values.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'This has upper-case VAL1.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'This has mixed-case VaLn.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'This has val100.' FROM DUAL;

Then you can create an Oracle Text index:
CREATE INDEX table_name__textfield__textidx
  ON table_name(textfield) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;

and use the query:
SELECT fieldname, textfield
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONTAINS(textfield, 'val1 OR val2 OR val3 OR valn', 1) > 0

Which outputs:



FIELDNAME
TEXTFIELD




2
This is some text where val1 is contained.


3
This has val2 and val3.


5
This has upper-case VAL1.


6
This has mixed-case VaLn.



The row containing val100 is not matched by val1 as they are different words. If you want to match the stem of words then use % in the contains filter:
SELECT fieldname, textfield
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONTAINS(textfield, 'val1% OR val2% OR val3% OR valn%', 1) > 0

Which outputs:



FIELDNAME
TEXTFIELD




2
This is some text where val1 is contained.


3
This has val2 and val3.


5
This has upper-case VAL1.


6
This has mixed-case VaLn.


7
This has val100.



fiddle

If you store values you're looking for into a val column of a separate_table, you could simplify query to
SELECT a.fieldname 
FROM table a join separate_table s on a.textfield like '%' || s.val || '%'

Efficiency? Nothing is very efficient with that kind of a search. Perhaps you could take a look at Oracle Text and see what kind of search it offers.
